# DotNetNuke , The specified password for user account “sa” is not valid

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am installing DotNetNuke, during installation it is asking Database Password, I am giving the same password that I am using for SQL server but it is showing error.

> The specified password for user account “sa” is not valid, or failed to connect to the database server

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It seems that DNN is using a different sql server instance than you are using.

Answer (score 5):

You likely aren't configuring a complex enough SA password, though the Web Platform Installer won't tell you what the requirements are (likely 7 characters, with something other than just alpha)

As Daniel said, I detest the WPI and avoid it like the plague. When it works, it works great, but when it doesn't, it is really painful to troubleshoot

Comment: Then why is it saying, "the specified password for user account sa is not valid or failed to connect to the database server"?!  It is the valid password, and it can connect.  It should say, "please change the SA password to make it more complex and then reconnect with that password."  Even weirder is that if SQL is not installed, it'll first install SQL for you and allow you to create an SA password which it will later reject.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the steps [described here](http://www.markeckeard.com/post/2013/03/19/SA-issues-installing-DNN-using-Web-Platform-Installer-45.aspx), this solved my issue:

> 1. Log in to SQL Server using .\sqlexpress and windows authentication
> 2. Expand Security, then Logins
> 3. Look at the icon.  If there's a small arrow pointing down, the account is disabled.  Let's fix that.
> 4. Double-click the sa account to open properties.
> 5. Change the password (strong using password policy)and confirm it.
> 6. Click on "Status" in the left pane to reload the options in the right pane.  Select "Enabled" under the header "Login".
> 7. Click "OK" to close the properties window.
>
> With the sa account taken care of, we need to check to ensure we're in
> mixed mode:
>
> 1. While in SSMS, right-click the server name in the left pane and select "Properties"
> 2. Click "Security" in the left pane and select "SQL Server and windows authentication mode".
> 3. Click "OK".
> 4. Close SSMS.
>
> The last step is to restart SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) under control
> panel --> administrative tools --> services.
>
> Once this is done, log in to SQL Server 20008 Express using the sa account and password that you changed.  If successful, you can now install DNN using the web platform installer.

Comment: -1 for copying contents without any proper attribution.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I am using a strong password and SSMS can connect to .\sqlexpress as 'sa' with this password, but WebPI is always saying the password is not valid...

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue it took me few months to workout. What i did was following;

Open Webmetrix as "Administrator" Hold Shift Key + Right click on Webmetrix

it will ask you for Administrator password.

Install Webmatrix (make sure you know 'SA' password)

This should work like charm

Thanks,
Yogs

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a great answer for you but I can tell you that I had a lot of issues using the web platform installer. I now prefer to download the regular installation package and just do it manually. It is not very complicated:

- you unzip it then move or copy all files to the IIS website directory
- then you make sure the worker process has full rights on the folder
- you create your database with a user
- you navigate to the site and the installer just strats right in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use **server** as password. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to follow the password complexity for SQL Server by following the link: 
[Password Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161959.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your instance is configured for sql authentication and windows authentication.  Check your logs may find something there.